# Modify document library view on all subsites in a site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I have close to 1000 subsites in a site collection.  I would like to remove the country column from the defualt view in each site with one power shell script.  This is how I would do it for one site, but how do I get this script to run for all subsites?

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://server_name/sitecollection/"
$spList = $spWeb.GetListFromUrl("property documents/forms/AllItems.aspx")
$spView = $spList.DefaultView
$spView.ViewFields.Delete("Country")
$spView.Update()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `SPSite.AllWebs` property...

Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980124/sharepoint-2010-powershell-loop-through-all-document-libraries-create-view-a), as it is very similar.

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://server_name/sitecollection/"
$web = $site.RootWeb
foreach($spList in $web.Lists) { 
    $spView = $spList.DefaultView      
    $spView.ViewFields.Delete("Country")      
    $spView.Update() 
}
```

This is assuming all lists have the Country field. You can check that if all of them don't...

Hope that helps

Comment: +1 That's what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

There is a script that you can use to traverse through all sites and subsites, to get you started.

The script can be found here:

http://geekswithblogs.net/bjackett/archive/2011/09/19/powershell-script-to-traverse-all-sites-in-sharepoint-2010-or.aspx